# Как к одному массиву применить toLowerCace и indexOf?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
["php", "kotlin",  "php", "css", "CSS", "Kotlin", "python" ,"script", "script", 
"html", "HTML", "java", "c++", "Html", "Ruby",];
```

Нужно написать функцию, которая возвращает массив, в котором удалены повторяющиеся элементы из массива.
ps: Мы не знаем в каком регистре у нас будут строки в массиве.

Застопорился на том, что не могу понять, как, после того как привел все в нижний регистр, осуществить удаление повторяющихся элементов.Пробую с помощью indexOf но лучшее чего я добился это то что indexOf не видит того что применялся toLowerCace и соответственно не сортирует повторяющиеся элементы.

```js
var arr = ["php", "kotlin", "php", "css", "CSS", "Kotlin", "python", "script", "script",
  "html", "HTML", "java", "c++", "Html", "Ruby",
];

var result = [];

function rerepeat() {
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    var newArr = item.toLowerCase();
    if (result.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      result.push(item);
    }
    console.log(result);
  });
}

rerepeat();
```

Comment: результат `toLowerCase` ты сохраняешь в `newArr` а используешь везде `item`

Comment: Почему не `Set`?

Comment: Grundy - спасибо.Два дня бился!! А тут так просто все оказалось!!!

Comment: Денис Степанов - не Set - потому как я первый раз об этом узнал.Я же мега начинающий)))

Comment: `[...(new Set(arr.map(_ => _.toLowerCase())))]`

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов, плохое решение, если нужны элементы из массива.

Answer (score 0):

> Плохое решение, если нужны элементы из массива. @Grundy

```js
const arr = ["Php", "Kotlin", "Php", "Css", "CSS", "Kotlin", "python", "script", "script",
  "html", "HTML", "java", "c++", "Html", "Ruby", "JAva", "HTml", "RUby",
];

const getFiltered = (arr) => [...(new Set(arr.map(_ => _.toLowerCase())))];

console.log(getFiltered(arr));
```

Если вам все таки из исходного массива надо элементы выбрать :)

```js
const arr = ["Php", "Kotlin", "Php", "Css", "CSS", "Kotlin", "python", "script", "script",
  "html", "HTML", "java", "c++", "Html", "Ruby", "JAva", "HTml", "RUby",
];

function getFilteredList(arr) {
  const toLowerCase = "".split.call.bind("".toLowerCase);

  const toLowerSet = new Set(arr.map(toLowerCase));
  return arr.filter(word => (toLowerSet.has(word.toLowerCase()) && toLowerSet.delete(word.toLowerCase())))
}

console.log(getFilteredList(arr))
```